# How to populate html on Ajax success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I don't know how to write the success function to write the html below.

I'm guessing I need to use a for loop and populate  with each record returned in the json

my js

```
<script>
    function UpdateStatus(){
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:"/get_records/",
                data: {
                    product:"test",
                },
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

the html I want populated:

```
<div class="editview-product-box">
    <H3>record</H3>
    <div class="editview-radio-box">
        {% for record in records %}
        <input type="radio" name="{{ record }}" /> {{ record }}
        <br /> {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

the current js works because I can see the api response in chrome dev network panel - however I can't get anything to log to the console for some reason, not sure why.

Comment: what is in `data` you need to append values from javascript?

Comment: What response are you getting?

Comment: Where you want to populate the given HTML ?

Comment: inside <div class = "editview-product-box"> </div>

Comment: See [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) ~ `$('.editview-product-box').load('/get_records/?product=test')`

Comment: i think this would just load raw JSON into the div - I want to actually construct the html using a for loop as seen in OP

Comment: You and to append `<input type="radio" name="{{ record }}" />` after ajax success ?

Comment: Your question is unclear then. You specifically said _"How to populate HTML..."_. Please show **exactly** what the HTML looks like in your page before the AJAX request and how you'd like it to look after **AND** show **exactly** what the response data looks like

Comment: yes @KiranShahi i think this is what i want

Comment: @david so you are getting `data.records` in response on ajax success?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On ajax success you need to append html to selected element / selector. Here is an working example.

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos",
    data: {
        product: "test",
    },
    success: function(data) {
        onSuccess(data);
    }
});

function onSuccess(data) {
  let html = "";
  $.each(data, function(k, v){
    html += `<input type="radio" name="${v.id}" /> ${ v.title }<br />`
  })
  $('.editview-radio-box').html(html);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="editview-product-box">
    <H3>record</H3>
    <div class="editview-radio-box">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the twig template is fetched from backend without value but with expressionsin ajax call.

If the above code given is twig template, then it should be rendered thoroughly from backend, the variables cannot generate the values in html from javascript.